# SharePoint Hosted Add In REST API returns null for lookup field values

Tags: sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-rest-api, lookup-column, 2019, app-permissions

I have written following REST Query in SharePoint Hosted Add In to get list items:

```
<appweburl>/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('PageAccessMatrix')/items?$select=Headers,GranitePageLink/PageLink,PageName/Title&$expand=GranitePageLink,PageName&$filter=InsideNavigation%20eq%201&@target=%27<hostweburl>%27
```

However, everything is working fine in development and production environments and after I restored the database of  production to make UAT environment, the same above query is returning null value of lookup fields (i.e. GranitePageLink and PageName) for non-farm account users accessing the SharePoint Hosted Add In.

If I run the same REST query outside the context of SP Hosted Add In then it works fine for all users in UAT environment.

Following troubleshooting I have performed:

1. Lookup fields having proper data in list
2. Checked the lookup fields relation in list - OK
3. Created new lookup fields - still returns null

On Premise Environment-

SharePoint Server: 2019

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: I think you may need to recreate the lookup columns. Because, I have seen that the lookup columns not getting created properly when creating a list using list templates. You please check the specific column settings once again / try creating a new item and check lookup values are displaying correctly.

Comment: I created new column but still same issue. It is working with farm account and not working for other users. @JefinMathew